# c++ keeps deleting my line in text file

Tags: c++

I have a simple program where it will ask the user for the year, make and model of a car then it will write it into a text file.

The program runs and writes the line in the text file but once I run it again to put something else, it is deleting my first line with the new input.

Do I need to "open the file" outside of the function?

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class automobile
{
public:
    // Constructor
    automobile(int year, string make, string model)
    {
        setcarYear(year);
        setcarMake(make);
        setcarModel(model);
    } //  end of constructor

    void setcarYear(int year)
    {
        carYear = year;
    }

    int getcarYear() {
        return carYear;
    }

    void setcarMake(string make) {
        carMake = make;
    }

    string getcarMake()
    {
        return carMake;
    }

    void setcarModel(string model)
    {
        carModel = model;
    }

    string getcarModel() {
        return carModel;
    }

    int carYear;

    string carMake;
    string carModel;
};

int main() {
    ofstream myfile("auto.txt");
    ifstream myfile1("auto.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        int year;
        string make, model;
        cout << "Please enter the year of the car" << endl;
        cin >> year;
        cout << "Please enter the make of the car" << endl;
        cin >> make;
        cout << "Please enter the model of the car" << endl;
        cin >> model;
        automobile automobile(year, make, model);

        // display user info
        myfile << automobile.getcarYear() << "  " << automobile.getcarMake() << "  " << automobile.getcarModel() << "  " << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use code like below. It will append the content of the file instead of override.

```
ofstream myfile ("auto.txt", ios::app);
```

**NOTE:**
**`ios::app`** All output operations are performed at the end of the file, appending the content to the current content of the file.